# Regex match one specific character or numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regex that matchs a string with one specific character (Uppercase or Lowercase), let's say `F` o numbers.

It should match:

- f
- F
- 1
- 0
- 12
- 134

It shouldn't match

- f1
- F0
- 23F
- fast
- Fall234

Comment: -> `^([fF]|\d+)$`

Comment: That's the one I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
(^[fF]$)|(^\d+$)
```

Working example: 
https://regex101.com/r/gox5Y1/1/